# Defense tactics in a supernatural mist

Tags: survival, tactics

> You're struggling through, your breath flashing quick and hard, in and out of your nose, your nostrils flaring from the intensity. In and out goes your breath -  and so too - in and out goes the fog. Every step you take is an agony, the mass of bloody scores on your calf causing you pain with every step, and for what? Your feet seem to take you no where, having no purpose. And then the noises come. On the very edge of hearing, at the point where imagination and reality mingle, footsteps are heard. Scamperings, clatterings, clicks. Your throat closes up, you rush forward - but to where?

This question has to do with the idea of how would someone defend themselves in a supernatural fog. The fog in question is more than just a gathering of water droplets, but a malevolent force, instilling in whoever enters it a sense of fear. Furthermore, dangerous creatures live inside of it, such as oversized spiders, something that appears to be a bear crossed with a chimpanzee, and near all other assorted monsters. In the face of these dangers, either by yourself or in the company of others, what would be the best survival tactics? Any gear and preparation is allowed, as long as it fits within the proper frame (a mix of renaissance and industrialised 1900s).

Comment: Smells like someone is burning marijuana oh wait no... giant spiders are chasing me... again.

Comment: Fly above it in a balloon? Wear a gas mask? How much does the character need to engage with these threats?

Comment: What resources are available? Are we talking civilians in a city? Soldiers in a military base? Hikers in the wilderness?

Comment: Try reading Cherie Priest's Clockwork Century Series, she has a gas that will kill you, and keeps everything... foggy

Comment: *Find the nearest mall and fortify it, kick out religious fanatics.* Use polearms to poke for monsters.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the technology available, I'm assuming that it is steam/gear-punk. That being said, I'm also going to split this into two categories: If there are renaissance-level weapons or 1900's weapons.
To begin:

**IF RENAISSANCE WEAPONS ARE AVAILABLE**

If the weapon technology is at Renaissance level, he could be carrying a shot gun, (That is, a gun that fires a kind of ammo called shot) a wall gun, a volley gun, a crossbow, a regular bow, (Long, short, recurve, whatever) or any manner of sharp/pointy metal objects.

**IF 1900'S INDUSTRIAL WEAPONS**

If your character has access to the weapons of the 19th century, (I say 19th because you have a little bit of the 20th, but all of the 19th available) then you can choose from all manner of wonderful guns. (I personally prefer the Mosin-Nagant M-91.) You may also choose grenades. Or they could go the route of [Jack "Mad Jack" Churchill](http://www.vice.com/read/the-strange-tale-of-the-british-soldier-who-killed-nazis-with-a-sword-and-a-longbow).

Now onto the strategy.

The character could send out small clockwork devices with candles or lanterns mounted to them to see If the area in that line is clear. If it is, they could walk through. If it's not, they could use their weapons to defend him/herself, however crudely, because of the supernatural terror that is gripping your character. That's bound to have an effect on aim.
As for the fog itself, they could use a gas mask if one is available, or counter it with magic incense. If you want them to counter it at all.
In any case, I imagine a lot of running or standing still, with no in-between. This is to either distance themselves from the spiders and other creepy things, or to avoid detection.